# ¿Cómo traducir "Sidekick"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término

Ayer fui a recoger mis gafas nuevas, y la dependienta me preguntaba "where are your *sidekicks*?" en referencia a mi mujer y mi hijo de dos años, que anduvo zascandileando por la tienda la semana pasada, cuando fui a hacerme las gafas.

El diccionario define `sidekick` como:

> a person's assistant or close associate, especially one who has less authority than that person.

Wordreference propone como [posibles traducciones](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=sidekick)

> secuaz, compinche

Pero no me gusta ninguna de esas traducciones, ya que tienen ciertas connotaciones, como si ambas personas estuviese enredando o formasen parte de una banda.

Un *sidekick* es más que un "esbirro, secuaz, compinche o ayudante". Robin es el sidekick de Batman, y el Capitan America tiene su propio *sidekick*, Bucky. Incluso podemos pensar en Sancho Panza como el *sidekick* de Don Quijote. Asi que mas que un simple ayudante el *sidekick* se convierte a veces en un `protegido` o un `aprendiz`. Es incluso más que eso, es un "[close companion or colleague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidekick)", de acuerdo a Wikipedia, apelando a que a difencia de los "henchmen, minions, or lackeys" de los villanos, los héroes forman un vínculo con sus *sidekicks*.

A mí lo mejor que se me ocurre es `compañero de aventuras`, pero esta traducción deja fuera la connotación de que el *sidekick* suele ser un protegido, con menos habilidad o experiencia que el personaje principal en la literatura.

¿Cuál sería una mejor traducción para **sidekick**?

Comment: ¡Qué palabra tan chula! No la conocía. Para estas cosas me gusta mucho consultar Linguee, pues ofrece traducciones en contexto. En este caso [sugiere](http://www.linguee.es/ingles-espanol/traduccion/sidekick.html) _comparsa_ (del original _mere sidekick_). También el [ministerio del interior](http://www.interior.gob.es/documents/642317/1203227/Diccionario_de_terminos_juridico-policiales_126150938.pdf/90d45138-594b-480f-a01e-aa58104f6abe) habla de _compinche_ y _colega_, pero siguen sin convencerse. Finalmente, Google translate lo deja en _compañero_, sin más, o bien _socio_.

Comment: A mi me gusta _compinche_, entre personas con cierta confianza es una palabra divertida, sin el sentido negativo que puede tener en otros ámbitos. También creo que podría usarse _camarada_.

Comment: @blonfu a mí _compinche_ me suena muy divertida también, mientras que _camarada_ la veo fuera de contexto aquí. Al fin y al cabo, se refiere a la mujer y la hija. A todo esto, creo que vale decir que el uso de _sidekicks_ en el contexto que describe Diego fue en broma (de lo contrario, eso de _one who has less authority_ podría tener mala connotación)

Comment: Secuaz tiene algo de connotación negativa y aplica para villanos. Compinche es la que yo usaría para compañero. En el sentido de que es protegido y esta en proceso de entrenamiento (como lo es un _padawan_ a un Jedi) puede usarse "aprendiz"

Comment: @fedorqui tienes razón, _camarada_ suena un poco rara y forzada para referirse a familiares.

Comment: blonfu, Thank you! Speaker of American English here, second language semifluent spoken Mexican Spanish, looking for a non-perjorative translation of sidekick which still carries the clear connotation of a subordinate or dependent position. I used sidekick to describe a relative's clingy but otherwise charming girlfriend who followed him everywhere but the bathroom, but could not think of a Spanish word that indicated the dependency without being unkind. Acolito/a looks like the best fit so far: I am gratefully adopting it!

Comment: Una acepción jocosa sería "churumbeles".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pesar de que considero [adlátere](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0m2Qr5J), propuesto por [user](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/14480/user), como la palabra ideal para traducir "*sidekick*" debo admitir que (desgraciadamente) no la he visto usada coloquialmente.

Dicho eso, voy a proponer algunas alternativas basadas tanto en traducciones previamente aceptadas como términos usados en español para describir el concepto.

Tal como menciona [Ramon-san](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/14489/ramon-san), Sancho Panza es el primer personaje en una obra de literatura española que toma ese rol en particular, precediendo a Robin por unos cuantos siglos. Los términos usados para Sancho son "*escudero*", "*mozo*" "*compañero*", "*acompañante*", "*ayudante*", "*vasallo*", "*criado*" y "*sirviente*". En los análisis literarios Sancho es descrito como su "*complemento*", "*contrapunto*", "*secuaz*", "*cómplice*" y su "*acompañamiento*".

Por otra parte, Robin ya lleva décadas con artículos dedicados al análisis de su personaje. En esos artículos se le refiere principalmente como "*compañero*", "*acompañante*", "*asistente*" y "*compinche*".

En el contexto de la dependienta, la manera más natural de preguntarlo en español sería "*¿Dónde están tus acompañantes?*" o "*¿Dónde está tu acompañamiento?*" (o menos común "*¿Dónde está tu corte?*").

Finalmente, de las opciones presentadas relativas a Sancho, resaltan las siguientes:

- Escudero
- Mozo
- Vasallo
- Criado
- Sirviente

Estos términos describen una relación de servitud, de un asistente cercano que tiene menor autoridad a la persona a la que acompaña. Los últimos dos términos no me agradan tanto al realizar una comparación con "*sidekick*" pero los tres primeros son más naturales (a pesar de que el término "*escudero*" no es completamente actual) para describir el rol.

**Nota**: A pesar de que tenía reservas de usar el término "*escudero*" para Robin, al parecer hay [varios](http://los40.com/los40/2014/06/23/cinetv/1403518265_370680.html) [ejemplos](http://www.nosologeeks.es/2012/07/19/semana-batman-era-joel-schumacher-batman-forever-batman-robin/) [de](http://www.teinteresa.es/cine/evolucionado-Batman-largo-historia_0_1180082352.html) [su](http://blogdesuperheroes.es/resenas-batman-y-robin-2) [uso](http://www.blogdecine.com/tag/batman-robin) [en](http://www.culturaocio.com/tv/noticia-mas-detalles-titans-robin-traicionado-batman-20150514135434.html) [artículos](http://www.melty.es/batman-vs-superman-sera-jason-todd-el-robin-que-acompane-al-caballero-oscuro-a164459.html) [en](http://www.elmulticine.com/noticias2.php?orden=457790) [español](http://archivo.larazon.viapais.com.ar/interesa/Robin-escudero-bobo-tiempos_0_636600135.html). Supongo que dado que Batman en la actualidad ha sido designado como "*el caballero oscuro*" lo más natural es que Robin sea su "*escudero*".

**Notas adicionales**:

Ahondando en la relación particular entre Robin y Batman, se ha utilizado el término "*protegido*" ya que existe una diferencia de edad entre ambos y Batman cuenta con cierta responsibilidad sobre Robin. Sin embargo, esta relación en particular es más de maestro y discípulo por lo que, viéndolo desde ese punto de vista, los términos *aprendiz*, *pupilo* y *discípulo* se pueden utilizar para describir parte del rol de Robin. Bajo esta perspectiva, Robin sería un aprendiz de caballero moderno: El "*aprendiz*" del caballero oscuro.

Cabe mencionar que un "*sidekick*" no necesariamente es un *aprendiz* sólo que en las instancias de los "*sidekicks*" de los héroes ese es su rol principal. Es decir, se puede considerar las historias de super héroes como las historias de caballeros modernos en una cruzada en nombre de la justicia, y a sus "*sidekicks*" como a sus "*aprendices*".

Lo anterior es para resaltar que en el caso de los "*sidekicks*" de los super héroes se les puede considerar como un aprendiz que sirve de escudero durante cierto tiempo, hasta que ocurren los conflictos con sus "*maestros*" al estar listos para ser *héroes* por sí mismos. Historias más maduras exploran cuando los jóvenes héroes llegan a ese punto, ejemplos de series que ahondan en este tema serían "*Teen Titans*" y "*Young Justice*".

Comment: +1, me encanta `escudero`. Creo que recoge el sentido muy bien, a pesar de tener connotaciones de arcaísmo. Robin es definitivamente el escudero de Batman, ya que en su universo de ficción son cruzados modernos.

Comment: @Diego también me gusta mucho el término escudero, que siempre lo relaciono internamente con Robin. Mis dudas para proponerlo eran las connotaciones de arcaísmo que mencionas y que no sabía si el término se usaba en artículos para Robin pero actualizaré la respuesta con el resultado de mi investigación.

Comment: Me surge la duda de si _"escudero"_ no es una escritura redundante: normalmente sugerimos palabras o bien entrecomillándolas, o bien poniéndolas en cursiva. Las dos cosas a la vez se ve raro.

Comment: @fedorqui No estoy seguro, desde la universidad he notado que los términos en comillas y las citas de libros y artículos que leía estaban estilados en cursivas y desde ahí procuro hacerlo de esa manera. No sé si existe una regla o si cuando lo noté los libros y artículos estaban en inglés, creo que esa sería una buena pregunta a hacer a la comunidad.

Comment: Parece que tenemos respuesta en el [DPD en comillas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=SSTAZ5sDyD6h59vijX): _d) Cuando en un texto manuscrito se comenta un término desde el punto de vista lingüístico, este se escribe entrecomillado: La palabra «cándido» es esdrújula. En los textos impresos, en lugar de usar las comillas, se escribe el término en un tipo de letra diferente al de la frase en que va inserto (en cursiva si el texto normal va en redonda, o en redonda si el texto normal va en cursiva)_. Por tanto, entiendo que sería suficiente decir _sidekick_, en cursiva y sin comillas.

Answer (score 10):

[**Adlátere**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0m2Qr5J)

> Alterac. del lat. *a latĕre* 'al lado', por confusión de las preps. lats. *a* 'desde' y *ad* 'junto a'.
>
> 1. adj. Dicho de una cosa: Aledaña o supeditada a otra. U. t. c. s.
>
> 2. m. y f. despect. Persona subordinada a otra de la que parece inseparable.

Comment: +1 Debo reconocer que esta respuesta me ha sorprendido mucho.

Comment: Buena propuesta. He oído la palabra muchas veces y, ciertamente, con el significado que busca la pregunta. Sobre todo en plural (de hecho, hasta ahora pensaba que el singular era *adláter*, pero ya veo que estaba equivocado).

Comment: +1, me gusta mucho esta respuesta (candidata a mejor respuesta!)

Comment: _Adlátere_ yo siempre lo he visto usado de forma peyorativa, me sentaría  bastante mal que alguien llamara a mis familiares _adláteres_, en la propia definición del DLE también lo pone: _m. y f. despect._

Answer (score 4):

Si bien parece usarse solo en Argentina, podría valer [ladero](https://dle.rae.es/ladero):

> 2. m. *Arg*. Persona que secunda a otra, particularmente a un caudillo político.

Answer (score 3):

Aparte del *compinche* que menciona @blonfu en un comentario, me gusta la palabra [acólito](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0WsNdwK). Si bien sus significados principales en español son religiosos, también se ha extendido a otros ámbitos, volviendo al significado etimológico de la palabra (*el que sigue o acompaña*).

Esta palabra puede tener un sentido algo peyorativo en algunos casos, haciendo referencia a alguien que nunca va a ningún sitio sin su jefe; pero lo mismo ocurre con el inglés *sidekick*. Pero ese sentido peyorativo puede ser más humorístico en casos como los de la pregunta, cuando hacen referencia a familiares, especialmente si son niños (nadie puede considerar criticable que un niño acompañe a sus padres).

Comment: Viendo la entrada de acólito en el DRAE aparece  _satélite_ en último lugar, me ha hecho gracia ya que es una palabra que usa mi padre con algunos de sus amigos y no se me había ocurrido para este caso.

Answer (score 2):

¿Qué tal [deuteragonista](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Db0Re2P)?

> En las obras literarias o análogas, personaje que sigue en importancia al protagonista.

Comment: +1 por aportar un término tan poco conocido y completamente válido. En cualquier caso, aunque sea uno de los más apropiados que se han aportado, me temo que si le dijese a alguien que vengo con mis _deuteragonistas_ me pondrían la misma cara que si les dijese que vengo con mis _sidekicks_. Aparte, puede el villano principal de uan obra ser el deuteragonista (piensa en un Darth Vader para Luke Skywalker u otro tipo de _antagonista_)? Hay personajes que "siguen en importancia" y que no necesariamente son un apoyo o compañía del personaje principal.

Answer (score 1):

[Satélite](https://dle.rae.es/sat%C3%A9lite):

> 3. m. Persona o cosa que depende de otra y está sometida a su influencia. U. t. en apos.

Answer (score 0):

En la ocasión a la que refieres, yo utilizaría la palabra **acompañante**.

Como Sancho Panza es el acompañante de Don Quijote en sus aventuras.